# D3js single bar graph the updates via a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, graph, d3.js, slider

I am attempting to create a simple bar graph that updates when you change a slider value, I am having a couple of issues. I don't know how to update a attribute of the svg element when changing the slider without drawing a whole new svg element thus creating two, three four elements.....

you can view it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kitsondevelopment/3HL4a/159/)

Here is my code

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({ max: 50 });

$( "#slider" ).slider({ min: 10 });



$( "#slider" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
   var selection = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
    console.log(selection);



                //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 50;

            //Data
            var dataset = [];

      dataset.push(selection);

      console.log(dataset);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height", 50);

            var rectangle = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect");





            rectangle.attr("width", 20)

            .attr("height", function(d){
                return d;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d){
                return 20;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d){
                return 20;
            });


  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have made one tiny but significant change in the fiddle that I think you might like: listening to the slide event rather than the change one makes the response to the sliding motion continuous (and in my opinion, more pleasant). I added that to the post. Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of changes were necessary.

Change to the handling of the enter/update selection:

```
var rectangle = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset);

rectangle
    .enter()
    .append("rect");

rectangle
    .attr("width", 20)
    ...
```

Change to the placement of the SVG element outside the slider handler.

Complete [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/160/).

NOTE: the current height of the SVG element is not sufficient to see the magnitude of changes allowed by the slider. You should increase that, say `attr("height", 200)`.

Another [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/163/) responding to the slide event and thus making the change to the rect's height more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: How do I make the rectangle grow **up** instead of down?

Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out if anyone needs it:

.attr("transform", function(d, i){
                return "translate(20, 500) rotate(180)"; 
              })

This will place the rectangle in the lower left corner of a 500x500px svg container, the 20 is the width of the rectangle.